# Passing config to ExtJS prototypes

Tags: config, extjs4

I'm trying to figure out how ExtJS4 passes around config objects.
I want to do the equivalent of...

```
store  = function(config){
    if ( typeof config.call !== 'unndefined' ){
        config.url = "server.php?c=" + config.call || config.url;       
    };  
    Sketch.Data.AutoSaveStore.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};
Ext.extend(store, Ext.data.Store{})
```

I am probably missing something obvious here, but having dug around in the sandbox file, the closest I have come is....

```
 Ext.define('My.awesome.Class', {
     // what i would like to pass.
     config:{},
     constructor: function(config) {
         this.initConfig(config);
         return this;
     }
 });
```

which doesn't seem to work if you do something like...

```
var awesome = Ext.create('My.awesome.Class',{
    name="Super awesome"
});  
alert(awesome.getName()); // 'awesome.getName is not a function'
```

However

```
  Ext.define('My.awesome.Class', {
     // The default config
     config: {
         name: 'Awesome',
         isAwesome: true
     },
     constructor: function(config) {
         this.initConfig(config);
         return this;
     }
 });

var awesome = Ext.create('My.awesome.Class',{
    name="Super awesome"
});  
alert(awesome.getName()); // 'Super Awesome'
```

This is biting me in the rear end when trying to do complex store extensions.
Anyone have any idea how I pass a bunch of random params to the prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using new operator to create new instance on your class. In ExtJS4, you should use `Ext.create()` method.

Try doing:

```
var awesome = Ext.create('My.awesome.Class');
alert(awesome.getName());
```

And if you want to pass some param when creating an instance, you can do the following

```
var awesome = Ext.create('My.awesome.Class',{name:'New Awesome'});
```

Comment: Indeed. the point is more towards the fact that I tried getting a variable that I had not declared beforehand, which I used to be able to do. Eg declaring config:{} in the define brings up a js error "awesome.getName is not a function"

Comment: I don't think you can create config and setter / getter methods dynamically.

Comment: using said methods as an example was a mistake, and since i have no intention of using said methods, and actually just want the config objects I pass in scope, that basically answers it for me. Thank you.